# ¿Qué es o como funciona esta parte del código - function (x)?

Tags: r

tengo este código

```
df = data.frame(
  group=c("Group 1","Group 1","Group 2","Group 2","Group 2"), 
  subgroup = c("A","A","A","A","B"),
  value = c(2,2.5,1,2,1.5))

aggregate(value~group, FUN = function(x) sum(x[x>2]), data=df)
```

no entiendo esa `function(x)` que quiere decir o como funciona esa función

Answer (score 0):

Cuando en el `aggregate` colocas `FUN = function(x)`estás utilizando una función personalizada.

Seguido del `function(x)`, vendrá la lógica de cómo tratar esos valores:

```r
sum(x[x>2]) // Sumar los datos mayores de 2
```

**Tenemos**:

```
Group 1 -> 2.5`.
Group 2 -> 0.0, ya que no hay ningún número en esa serie más grande que 2.
```

Esto, posiblemente sea una explicación sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

Es un tipo de clausula que se la conoce como función anónima (en otros lenguajes se le suele llamar lambda). En el contexto de `aggregate()`, el parámetro `FUN` espera que le indiques una función para tratar cada grupo de datos, podrías escribir tranquilamente algo así:

```
sumar_valores_mayores_a_2 <- function(x) {
  sum(x[x>2])
}

aggregate(value~group, FUN = sumar_valores_mayores_a_2, data=df)
```

Pero, ¿para que definir un nuevo objeto función que solo vas a usar en el contexto del `aggregate()`? esa es la idea de la función anónima. Son funciones que creas bajo demanda y que dejan de existir cuando ya la usaste, no llevan ningún nombre, por que no lo necesitan. En el ejemplo que te dí ¿que representa `sumar_valores_mayores_a_2`? basta simplemente ver la definición: `function(x) {sum(x[x>2])}` pero en este caso que se trata de una función de una sola línea, por lo que puedes prescindir de las llaves, finalmente todo queda: `function(x) sum(x[x>2]`. Las funciones anónimas, podrían tener múltiples parámetros, pero en este caso el `aggregate` espera una función con un único parámetro `x` (no importa el nombre) que se corresponde con el vector de cada grupo.

Comment: esta función `function(x) sum(x[x>2]` solo funciona con una sola linea o se le puede agregar mas lineas con esa sintaxis?

Comment: @Davitz, Puedes escribir todas las lineas que necesites, pero si tienes más de una linea debes si o si usar las llaves para encerrar el código